# Pattern matching search for different document types on Google AppEngine

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have a question that I would be grateful if you could answer me.

I need to implement a pattern matching search for different types of documents (including Google Docs, PDF, DOC, and so on). From my research in this regard, it seems that this kind of pattern matching cannot be straightforward on GAE.

Could I possibly ask you to guide me on how I can implement pattern matching on GAE? 
Do you recommend any open-source search engines or native Google search API to be customized for pattern matching search on GAE?

I would appreciate if you could answer me. 
Many thanks.

Regards,
Sargol

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK AppEngine is designed to strongly prefer data processing before writing it to the database rather than during/after reading it back. While this often leads to more stored data, it usually can increase application performance dramatically.

Applied to your case, I would say you should try to come up with a way of building and storing some sort of index for your documents at the time that you write them to the datastore. Then use this index for your pattern matching.

Since it's not clear from your question what exact kind of pattern matching you are talking about, it is difficult to give more specific advice. But if, for example, you are simply talking about a keyword search, you could, for each document, have a second entity in the datastore that stores the document's datastore key and contains a property with multiple values ([App Engine datastore: How to set multiple values on properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974243/app-engine-datastore-hot-to-set-multiple-values-on-properties)) listing all keywords present in the document. Then you can do a simple equals-query on these "index-objects" to find all documents that match your search terms.